# create a new column with variable but numbers are decimal instead of integer

Tags: r

I would like to create a new dataset

I gave that code

```
ch$n_new <- ch$new_ratio*ch$Population
```

Now I have numbers for ch$n_new like 2.5667 or 2.1900
But I want the number 3 for 2.5667 and 2 for 2.19
no decimal just integer. How can I fix that?

Comment: `ch$n_new <- round(ch$n_new)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didnt specify how you wanted to choose the integer - if you want to round to the nearest integer, use `round()`, if you want the lower integer value (floor) use `floor()` and if you want the higher integer value (ceiling) use `ceiling()`

```
x <- 3.1828

round(x)
floor(x)
ceiling(x)
```

Output

```
# > round(x)
# [1] 3
# > floor(x)
# [1] 3
# > ceiling(x)
# [1] 4
```

For your example, it seems `round()` would be meet your desired output:

```
y <- c(2.5667, 2.1900)

round(y)
#> round(x)
#[1] 3 2
```